# Access Checkbox value update does not trigger AfterUpdate event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I could not find an answer to my specific question, but I am also relatively new to VBA, so maybe I just didn't look for the right terminology.
What I have, is a form that contains a bunch of comboboxes. These are arranged in rows and columns like so:

```
cboThingOne1   cboThingTwo1   cboThingThree1
cboThingOne2   cboThingTwo2   cboThingThree2
...            ...            ...
cboThingOne15  cboThingTwo15  cboThingThree15
```

I have set `cboThingOne` to show a selection of items (e.g. `department1`, `department2`, `department3`,...) from an SQL database.

`cboThingTwo` and `cboThingThree` are also set to a certain Rowsource (containing things like `Apple`, `Bananas` and `Cherries`).

What I would like to happen is, as soon as I change the value in `cboThingOne1` to `department3`, to fill all of `cboThingOne` checkboxes with the same value. 
This is working. I am using the AfterUpdate event of each cbo, to call a function, which iterates over all items in `Me.Controls`, checks their name + 1 (in this case `cboThingOne2`) and sets the value of this control to `department3`.

```
Private Sub fun_fill_cbo_with_value(FieldName As String, FieldValue As String)
  Dim i as Integer
  'This function returns the name without number
  my_fieldname = Striptext(FieldName)
  'gets me the number of the field I am working with (i.e. cboThingOne1 --> 1)
  i = Int(Replace(FieldName, my_fieldname, ""))
  i = i+1
  cbo_name = my_fieldname + CStr(i)
  For Each my_control In Me.Controls
    If my_control.Name = my_fieldname Then
      my_control.Value = FieldValue
    End If
  Next my_control
End Sub
```

When the value for `cboThingOne2` is changed, I expected the AfterUpdate event of this cbo to be triggered, which apparently does not happen.

In this AfterUpdate event the Rowsource for `cboThingTwo2` should be updated.

```
Private Sub cboThingOne2_AfterUpdate()
  'To update the cbo in the row below
  Call fun_fill_cbo_with_value(cboThingOne2.Name, cbo_ThingOne2.value)
  Me.cboThingTwo2.RowSource = "somedifferentqueryhere"
  Me.cboThingThree2.Rowsource = "yetanotherquery"
```

What I expected, was that updating the value in `fun_fill_cbo_with_value` would update the value of the cbo + 1 (which works) and also triggers the AfterUpdate event (which does not happen).

Furthermore, because I am calling `fun_fill_cbo_with_value` in the AfterUpdate event, I expected the column to fill to the end, rather than just the cbo below (as it does right now).

I can fill the entire column of cbos, by adding an additional loop in `fun_fill_cbo_with_value` which just goes from 1 to 15.

That still does not help me with updating the rowsource of `cboThingTwo` and `cboThingThree`.

I hope you can help and if you need more information, I am glad to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected the AfterUpdate event of this cbo to be triggered, which
>   apparently does not happen.

It is triggered by a user action only.

Call the AfterUpdate event function itself from your code (bad practice); or (allows for better organised code) let the AfterUpdate event call a separate function which your other code can call as well.

Comment: I already tried something similar, but failed there. I was trying to call the AfterUpdate event of the current ```my_control``` but apparently couldn't get the syntax right. How would I call it from ```fun_fill_cbo_with_value```? Also, how would I construct the cboThingTwo2 name for example? So I could add a portion that does ```cbo.ThingTwo2.Rowsource = "something"``` in ```fun_fill_cbo_with_value```. Tried stuff like ```curr_cbo = "Me." & cbo_name``` and then do ```curr_cbo.RowSource = "something"``` but that did not work.